# fetch updated columns in MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

Is there a way to fetch the list of columns that have been updated in a MySQL "before update" trigger?  When a row is in a certain state, I want to make all but one column immutable.  So I'd like to access an array of modified columns, and if the array contains any column BUT the one column that should be able to be modified, I would reject the update.  SQL Server has COLUMNS_UPDATED( ), but I can't seem to find something similar for MySQL.

Comment: You need to compare `new.columnname` to `old.columnname` (for all columns you want to check), see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35343096). One thing to note: `COLUMNS_UPDATED( )` (and `update()`) in sql server do not check if the value was actually changed, just if the column was mentioned in the query. There is no equivalent to that in MySQL (you cannot determine if the column value stayed the same because it wasn't used in the query, or because it was assigned the same value), but your description does not seem to require this.

Comment: Thanks @Solarflare, I am aware of what you're describing, but that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.  I was hoping there was a way to see just the columns that have changed.  I have a lot of columns, and don't want to have to revise the trigger whenever a new column is added to the table.